# example to inserting event to google calendar api using oauth2 and calendar api v3

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I tried so many ways to insert the the event to google calendar using oauth2 and calendar Api v3. But I cant find any example.

Comment: Read this post: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ and then post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void createEvent(Calendar cal) throws IOException {       

Event event = new Event();
event.setSummary("Event name here");
event.setLocation("event place here");

Date startDate = new Date();
Date endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 3600000);
DateTime start = new DateTime(startDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
event.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(start));
DateTime end = new DateTime(endDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
event.setEnd(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(end));
Event createdEvent = cal.events().insert("primary", event).execute();
System.out.println("Created event id: " + createdEvent.getId());
}
```

Hope this code snippet might help you